# LibGDX: Gwt logging not working in my project

Tags: html, logging, gwt, libgdx

Don't worry, I'm not asking you to fix all my bugs, I just wanted to know common causes for gwt/html logging to not work.

Here is my project:
https://github.com/vedi0boy/Archipelo

I cannot get logging to work at all in html. I used this code in a brand new LibGDX project and it worked (inside the main class):

```
@Override
public void create () {
   Gdx.App.setLogLevel(Application.LOG_DEBUG);
   Gdx.app.log("Test", "Test log message.";
}
```

I just don't get it. Is there something common that could be making basic html/gwt functions not work? My libgdx is update to 1.9.2. I can't seem to figure out why it works on a new project but not mine.

What should I do? Should I attempt to copy all the code to a new project? Thanks.

P.S. I am also unable to use a networking library that I need, and it also works on a brand new project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple. I made a while loop that did not continue until a connection to the server was established. Since javascript is single threaded, it got caught in an infinite loop.

The reason this has to do with logging is because LibGDX only loads up the log box when create is finished being run and my infinite loop was in create so it never got around to rendering the logs.

Lesson: Don't treat JavaScript as a multi-threaded language when using GWT, because it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to copy all your code to a new project, if you have doubts about your LIBGDX version you can update your corruent project to a recent V of libgdx, 
use the `build.gradle` like follow :

```
gdxVersion = "1.5.2" // your gdx version here
```

for more info read **[this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Updating-LibGDX#switching-libgdx-versions)** topic in the official WIKI